# Grant permissions to the service account error

Tags: service, google-cloud-platform, permissions, text-to-speech, invalid-argument

Following step by step the example at,

https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-usage-python

on Step2, I get the following error.

```
D:\google-api-python\py>gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding [my-project-for-tts] --member "serviceAccount:[tts-python-1]@[my-project-for-tts].iam.gserviceaccount.com" --role "roles/owner"
ERROR: (gcloud.projects.add-iam-policy-binding) INVALID_ARGUMENT: Request contains an invalid argument.
```

What argument seems to be invalid here?

My intention is to use the **Text-to-Speech** services by loading a custom input text file and save the output in my local disk. I installed successfully *google-sdk* and *python*.

Comment: Is the `gcloud` the actual command that you used? you have to replace the parameters surrounded by `[...]` which real values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the square brackets are the invalid argument here. Using my own service account and running your command I get the same error, but removing the the [] runs fine.

If you remove the [] then the command will work fine.

Comment: Indeed that square brackets were the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As per the [Google Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/projects/add-iam-policy-binding), you need `=` to provide `member` and `role` value. Your command should look like below:

```
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding my-project-for-tts --member='serviceAccount:tts-python-1@my-project-for-tts.iam.gserviceaccount.com' --role='roles/owner'
```

Also, make sure you are using the latest `gcloud` package.